# clone a class object into a object of same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, clone

I have a class lets say students

with properties as

```
public string sname{get;set;}
public int sid{get;set;}
public studentprofile sprofile{get;set;}
```

where student profile is another class with some
other properties .

I want to do deep copy of the students object.

How to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do a deep copy an object in .Net (C# specifically)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is already answered. Have a look at this solution : [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)